# Django: Sort database import by the last entry first and so on

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-database

I am using the following to import the database entries  and it works fine by listing contents  from first entry to the last on the database:

users_temp = users.objects.all()    --> where users is a table in my database.

How do I change the above line so that I get a list of last item on the table first and so on?

Thanks,

Comment: i dint reallly understood what are you asking. do you want only last one? or from last to first?

Comment: It's common practice to use **upper case names** for your model classes, so you should consider using `Users` instead of `users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to get the list of users in a reverse order.

[`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.reverse) was made specifically for this:

> Use the reverse() method to reverse the order in which a queryset’s
>   elements are returned.

```
users.objects.all().reverse()
```